# ImportError: No module named tkinter in Sublime

Tags: python, linux, tkinter

Its not often, that I cannot find the answer for a problem, but now I do:

I run `MX-linux 4.19.05` on `AMD`.

When I use IDLE, there is not a problem, but when I try to run the same program in Sublime, I get this error message:

```
ImportError: No module named tkinter

[path: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games]
```

I know that tkinter is installed, since it runs fine under IDLE.

I searched for a solution, but so nothing so far.

Regards

Comment: Do you have different versions of python installed? There could be a path to a different version of python linked in your terminal and in your IDLE. Try importing the `sys` library and running `sys.version` and `sys.path` in both.

Comment: In IDLE:>>> sys.version
'3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) \n[GCC 6.3.0 20170516]'
>>> sys.path
['/home/henk/Programmeren/Python/RMS', '/home/henk', '/usr/bin', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/home/henk/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Comment: Sublime comes with no output (also no errors)

Comment: Could you try opening up a terminal and running `python` then `import sys`, `sys.version`, and `sys.path`? It seems like you might have tkinter installed on one version of python but not the other. Maybe double check you have it installed `sudo apt-get install python3-tk`

Comment: Thanks Eugene! You pointed me to the solution. Sublime pointed to Python 2.7. I made a new build, pointing to Python 3.5 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lX1vX8ejs40) THANX!!

Comment: Sweet, nice work! I wrote up an official answer

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be due to sublime and IDLE pointing to different versions of python.

Try running

```
import sys
sys.version
sys.path
```

in both IDLE and in a terminal window (with running `python` first in the terminal window).